# Group By, Sum in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

suppose I have the following table:

```
user type amount
2    a    10
2    b    20
2    c    40
3    a    15
3    b    20
3    c    45
```

I want to replace (c) amount with (c - (a+b)) grouping by the user and type, how could I do this? thanks

Comment: in LINQ to SQL, or do you already have the data in a typed collection (and thus, LINQ to Objects)?

Comment: I suppose that you mean that you want to group by the user value, as all combinations of user and type are unique?

Comment: LINQ to SQL, this is a genretaed datatable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a way:

*UPDATE* (now using `Sum`):

```
from item in table
group item by item.user into g
let a = (from i in g where i.type == "a" select i.amount).Sum()
let b = (from i in g where i.type == "b" select i.amount).Sum()
let c = (from i in g where i.type == "c" select i.amount).Sum()
select c - (a + b);
```

Comment: I assume there can be multiple entries per user of each type.

Comment: I didn't assume that, since the OP didn't specift this. In that case the query will be different (probably a `Sum` instead of `Single`).

Comment: I assumed it, because he is talking about `SUM` in the question title. His latest comment supports my assumption.

Comment: Fair enough. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest an expansion on **Steven**'s answer, since that will only return a sequence of scalar `c` values and not keep them associated with the users or the `a` and `b` amounts. Try this:

```
var query1 = from i in table
             group i by i.user
             into g
             let a = g.Where(t => t.type == "a").Sum(t => t.amount)
             let b = g.Where(t => t.type == "b").Sum(t => t.amount)
             let c = g.Where(t => t.type == "c").Sum(t => t.amount)
                   - (a + b)
             select new {user = g.Key, a, b, c};
```

Then, if you want to convert it back to tabular form:

```
var query2 = query1.SelectMany(q => new List<TableType>
                                    {
                                        new TableType(q.user, "a", q.a),
                                        new TableType(q.user, "b", q.b),
                                        new TableType(q.user, "c", q.c)
                                    })
                                    .OrderBy(t => t.user)
                                    .ThenBy(t => t.type);
```

Note: I've tested this and it works.